# GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider AccessToken not getting validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth

I am using the GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions class for authentication in my MVC5 Web App (SPA Template).  Given below is the code

```
var g = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "clientid",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    //CallbackPath="",
    Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:tokens:google:accesstoken",        ctx.AccessToken));
        }
    }
};
// restrict the retrieved information to just signin information
g.Scope.Add("openid");
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(g);
```

The token I get is something like this

```
ya29.LgAibra6cNLEKCEAAADLJxUOviZRgv9JSm-jrB-lNp16nomUijNrVAbcdDkI60Vg-A9yjFN4abcd_C8b4
```

I am using this token in subsequent calls to a MVC WebAPI which uses OAuthBearerTokens for security.  I send the access token through the header in my WebAPI call from my MVC Web app

```
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

The javascript generated on the client contains a much larger token which works with my MVC WebAPI.  Does anyone know how to fix this, plus why is the javaScript token different?  I suspect this has something to do with the SPA template itself but I am not sure.